# Создание программы со встроенной JVM

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, как создать программу со встроенной JVM и нужными библиотеками? Объясните по-подробней или киньте ссылки, где можно посмотреть.
Можно ли как-то автоматизировать этот процесс? Я использую InteliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 2):

Я использовал [Excelsior JET](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/jet.html) для компиляции моей Java в собственный исполняемый файл в Windows. Он работал очень хорошо. Всегда есть возможности для gotchas - я думаю, что JNI - проблема, но я был очень доволен.

Перевод https://stackoverflow.com/a/6700454/7847084